# why is tesseract missing easy numbers?

Tags: python-tesseract

I am trying to find the numbers in images like the one attached. I found that it helps when I run tesseract with the following parameters:

`numbers = pytesseract.image_to_string(maskArray,config ='--oem 3 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890')`

since I am looking for just numbers and they could be anywhere on the page. I found that tesseract can find 51416,51230, and 44133 but not 51523. At first I thought it may be a question of that dotted line behind the number, so I replaced that column with white. That did not seem to help. This image is already grayscale btw. One thing that seems to work is if I crop the image so that there is nothing left of that number. But in order to do that, I need to know where that number is. Any ideas what could be causing tesseract to randomly miss this number but not the other ones? or how to increase the accuracy?

Other things Ive tried:
rescaling up and down, inverting the image, blurring/unblurring, morphology/thresh,bilateral filter,erode , psm 11, 12, and default. Some combinations will increase the accuracy, but none seem to give me 100% which I would expect from the simplicity of the problem (currently maxing out at around 87%). Also, is there a way that I can increase the number of total outputs (including false positives)?

[image: sample image]

Comment: I suspect Tesseract doesn't like the dashed line to the left of 51523. To get rid of this line and also the leaders, you could make a mask. First dilate the image until the dashed line disappears. Then erode the image to get big black blobs. This is your mask to discard the portions of the image you don't want.

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but instead of dilating and eroding, I summed the columns and then if any columns were lower than a certain number (indicating black column) I changed that column to white. Unfortunately that did not help